# Convert bits to files

Tags: storage, converters, bit

I am currently working on something for storage and I am having issues; lets say I have a text file full of 1s and 0s how would one convert these to their original file. I don't mind if I have to use a program.

Comment: So you want to convert a text file full of bits to a binary file? What language? What did you try? This isn't a free coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read every 8 bits as 1 byte, and write that raw bytes as file.

Here is simplified Node.js example:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const content = fs.readFileSync('./input.txt');
const bits = content.toString();
const bytes = [];

for(let i=0;i<bits.length;i+=8){
    bytes.push(parseInt(bits.substr(i,8),2));
}

fs.appendFileSync('./output.bin', Buffer.from(bytes));
```